# Allowed memory size exhausted problem

Tags: plugins, dashboard, options, memory

This seems to be a weird problem. The exact error is this:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 337608 bytes) in ...
```

It only hangs the dashboard. The other part of website has no problem. The file name where the error happens is different at different time and I can't reproduce the error as I want.

Most probable reason of this error is activating plugin. So, I tried to activate all plugins one by one and the error occurred. I thought that plugin was the culprit. So to work in dashboard, I changed the name of the plugin via FTP and Dashboard was back. Then I renamed the plugin folder to its original name and activated the plugin again to reproduce the error.

But this time it activated without any problem. I tried activating, deactivating other plugins and the same thing happened again with another plugin. After renaming the plugin folder, the error wasn't gone this time. Instead, it showed the error was in `\wp-includes\functions.php` and when I reloaded `\wp-includes\theme.php`. After I reloaded again, it worked and Dashboard was back.

So, the problem is I can't seem to locate the origin of the problem. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: are you using a shared hosting?

Comment: @Sisir Yes. I'm using shared hosting.

Comment: Your server has _very_ little memory. The "allowed memory" works out to 64MB if I did the conversion correctly. Technically, that is minimum for Multisite and over the minimum a single install (last I checked) but I'd never run a site on that little RAM. @MarkKaplun has the right answer-- increase the memory. That may mean getting a better host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have enough memory allocated for your php script in your php.ini file. there are two ways to solve it

1. increase the memory allocation which might require you to increase the actual physical memory you use
2. give up on some features of your site.

There is no one root cause for such a problem which you can debug and "solve", the problem is a result of the actual usage of the accumulative features of your site and it is not caused by a single one of them (although probably one of them is more memory hungry then others)

Comment: I'm ready to sacrifice some features of my site. But how would I know which features I have to sacrifice without knowing where the problem is. I don't have to activate all the plugins to see the problems. It acts in random time with random plugins. So, how do I select which plugin to remove from my site?

Comment: you will need to analyze the code of the plugins for that. the path of increasing the memory is more simple and probably less expensive especially if you expect the traffic to your site to grow.